# Call method in other package by name?

Tags: reflection, methods, controller, go

I'm trying to call a method in another package by the name of the method (using the reflect package) but I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

What I'm trying so far is,

```
reflect.ValueOf(controller).MethodByName(action_name).Call()
```

(where controller is the other package)

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/56pdjuF0dXo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this using `pkg/reflect`. For this to work, packages would need to be first class citizens, which they are not.

Your best bet is to store the functions you want to access in a `map[string]interface{}` and look up 
the function in the map:

```
func Foo() { println("foo?") }

m := map[string]interface{}{
    "foo": Foo
}

f := m["foo"].(func())
f()
```